# How to calculate the position that the parameters should be pushed to when we use Windows x64 memory management by x64 assembly

Tags: windows, assembly, memory-management, x86-64, calling-convention

I was confused by some of the x64 assembly codes used for memory management, such as CreateFileA, WriteFile, and ReadFile. Whey creating a file by using WriteFile, they defined a couple of positions for the parameters that will be pushed to stack. For example,

```
.dwCreationDisposition equ 32
.dwFlagsAndAttributes equ 36
.hTemplateFile equ 40
```

The function structure for WriteFile is

```
HANDLE CreateFileA(
  [in]           LPCSTR                lpFileName, //8 bytes
  [in]           DWORD                 dwDesiredAccess, //4 bytes
  [in]           DWORD                 dwShareMode, //4 bytes
  [in, optional] LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes, //8 bytes
  [in]           DWORD                 dwCreationDisposition, //4 bytes
  [in]           DWORD                 dwFlagsAndAttributes, //4 bytes
  [in, optional] HANDLE                hTemplateFile //8 bytes
);
```

My guess for WriteFile: because all parameters would be pushed to the stack when calling the function in x86, but they are changed in x64. The first four parameters are passed to registers. Starting from the fifth, they will be pushed to stack. In x86, the hTemplateFile will be accessed by esp + 40,  dwFlagsAndAttributes by esp + 36. x64 assembly just follows this.

However, for the WriteFile, they use

```
.lpNumberOfBytesWritten equ 52
.lpOverlapped equ 0
.fileHandle equ 40

BOOL WriteFile(
  [in]                HANDLE       hFile,  //8 bytes
  [in]                LPCVOID      lpBuffer, //8 bytes
  [in]                DWORD        nNumberOfBytesToWrite, //4 bytes
  [out, optional]     LPDWORD      lpNumberOfBytesWritten, //8 bytes
  [in, out, optional] LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped  //8 bytes
);
```

I don't know how they calculate them.

Same to ReadFile, they use

```
.lpOverlapped2 equ 0
.lpNumberOfBytesRead equ 32
.lpBuffer equ 40

BOOL ReadFile(
  [in]                HANDLE       hFile,
  [out]               LPVOID       lpBuffer,
  [in]                DWORD        nNumberOfBytesToRead,
  [out, optional]     LPDWORD      lpNumberOfBytesRead,
  [in, out, optional] LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

Reference of codes : https://github.com/sonictk/asm_tutorial/blob/master/win_create_file.asm

I want to know how to calculate the position that the parameters should be pushed to when we use Windows x64 memory management by x64 assembly.

Comment: Don't follow that tutorial. The `lpOverlapped` is just wrong. The `lpNumberOfBytesWritten` is not the argument offset, it's a local variable that receives the number of bytes (this is not wrong just confusing). The address is passed in `r9`. The `lpNumberOfBytesRead` is wrong because that is the place for the 5th arg. The `mov rbp, rsp; sub rsp, 64` inside the function are nonsense as is the note on line 61.  There is more confusing or suboptimal code.

Answer (score 2):

Transfer of parameters into Windows function is a little bit more complicated in 64bit mode.

1. Make sure that RSP will be 16-bytes aligned before `CALL Function`.
2. Push parameters #last, #last-but-one, .... #5.
3. Create *shadow space* with `SUB RSP, 4*8`
4. Load parameters #4, #3, #2, #1 to registers R9, R8, RDX, RCX, respectively.
5. Call the imported function.
6. Restore RSP.

Inside the invoked function, (immediately when `CALL function` has been executed),  RSP is not 16-aligned, in fact the lowest bits of register SPL are `1000b` and RSP points at the return-address.
The first four parameters are available in registers, parameter #5 is at `[RSP+5*8]`, parameter #6 at `[RSP+6*8]` etc.

No matter if parameters are specified as HANDLE, LPVOID or DWORD, each corresponding slot on stack is always 8 bytes wide. x86 doesn't allow to push DWORD in 64bit mode.  See also this [example (Fast version)](https://euroassembler.eu/maclib/winabi.htm#WinABI_StackAlignment).

Comment: Note also that any instruction that modifies `rsp` must be annotated with unwind codes so that the system knows how to walk and unwind the stack. This is a commonly overlooked requirement in handwritten assembly. Almost nobody gets this part right.

Comment: @RaymondChen Is it also true when I do `MOV RBP,RSP` and use RBP for addressing the stack? I believe that SEH is required only for debugging with Microsoft tools, such as Visual Studio. I prefer to validate parameters before invokation and to check the returned error code, so I am not afraid of exceptions.

Comment: If you modify a nonvolatile register, you must mark it in the unwind codes so that it can be restored during unwind. You may not be afraid of exceptions, but maybe the lpNumberOfBytesWritten passed to WriteFile is a copy-on-write mapped resource. That will incur an exception on the write, which the system then handles by converting the page to writable and then resuming execution. Structured exceptions can happen for reasons outside your control and which you cannot protect against.

Comment: @RaymondChen, you're saying that a OS handled page fault exception on an out parameter may require walking the user's stack, what with unwind and all?

Comment: @ErikEidt Yes. This happens on writes to resource sections. The copy-on-write conversion is done by the top level exception handler, so the OS needs to walk up the stack through all the exception handlrrs to find it.