# Achieve automatic stack alignment and to adjust the stack for the FASTCALL calling convention

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, nasm, calling-convention

From this [Goasm Document](https://www.godevtool.com/GoasmHelp/64bits.htm#optim):

> The coding to achieve [automatic stack alignment](https://www.godevtool.com/GoasmHelp/64bits.htm#autoal) and to adjust the
> stack for the Windows x64 [FASTCALL calling convention](https://www.godevtool.com/GoasmHelp/64bits.htm#callingc) is as follows (which one is
> used depends on the number of parameters)

```
PUSH RSP             ;save current RSP position on the stack
PUSH [RSP]           ;keep another copy of that on the stack
AND SPL,0F0h         ;adjust RSP to align the stack if not already there
                     ;
                     ;  parameters dealt with here
                     ;
SUB RSP,20h          ;adjust RSP to provide placeholders
CALL TheAPI
LEA RSP,[RSP+xxh]    ;get RSP back to correct place for next
POP RSP              ;restore RSP to its original value
```

or

```
PUSH RSP             ;save current RSP position on the stack
PUSH [RSP]           ;keep another copy of that on the stack
OR SPL,8h            ;adjust RSP to align the stack if not already there
                     ;
                     ;  parameters dealt with here
                     ;
SUB RSP,20h          ;adjust RSP to provide placeholders
CALL TheAPI
LEA RSP,[RSP+xxh]    ;get RSP back to correct place for next
POP RSP              ;restore RSP to its original value
```

I'm interested in this Goasm statement:

> ...(which one is used depends on the number of parameters)...

After spending hours stack tracing in the windows debugger to understand the Goasm code, I've devised this MASM code to automatically align the stack to 16 bytes **before** the Windows function `call` and to restore the stack afterwards.

**MASM Example**

```
option casemap:none

extrn printf:proc
extrn ExitProcess:proc

ALIGN_STACK MACRO num_args
    IF num_args LT 5 OR (num_args AND 1) EQ 0
        AND SPL, 0F0h
    ELSE
        OR SPL, 08h
    ENDIF
ENDM

RESTORE_STACK MACRO num_args
    IF num_args LT 5
        LEA RSP, [RSP + 5*8]
    ELSEIF (num_args AND 1) EQ 0  ; even num_args
        LEA RSP, [RSP + (num_args + 1)*8]
    ELSE
        LEA RSP, [RSP + num_args*8]
    ENDIF
ENDM

.data
    strFormat6 db "%s %d %d %d %d",13,10,0
    strFormat5 db "%s %d %d %d",13,10,0  
    strFormat4 db "%s %d %d",13,10,0       
    strHello   db "Hello World",0
     
.code

main proc

    ; printf with 6 args

    NUM_ARGS        = 6               ; Number of function arguments
    PUSH            RSP               ; Save RSP on the stack
    PUSH            QWORD PTR [RSP]   ; Save another copy of RSP on the stack
    ALIGN_STACK     NUM_ARGS          ; Adjust RSP to align the stack if not already there
    PUSH            4                 ; ---+
    PUSH            3                 ;    |
    MOV             R9,2              ;    |-> Function arguments
    MOV             R8,1              ;    |
    LEA             RDX,strHello      ;    |
    LEA             RCX,strFormat6    ; ---+
    SUB             RSP,32            ; Shadow Space
    CALL            printf            ; Call the API
    RESTORE_STACK   NUM_ARGS          ; Get RSP back to correct place
    POP             RSP               ; Restore RSP to its original value
    
    ; printf with 5 args

    NUM_ARGS        = 5
    PUSH            RSP
    PUSH            QWORD PTR [RSP]
    ALIGN_STACK     NUM_ARGS
    PUSH            3
    MOV             R9,2
    MOV             R8,1
    LEA             RDX,strHello
    LEA             RCX,strFormat5
    SUB             RSP,32
    CALL            printf
    RESTORE_STACK   NUM_ARGS
    POP             RSP    
    
    ; printf with 4 args

    NUM_ARGS        = 4
    PUSH            RSP
    PUSH            QWORD PTR [RSP]
    ALIGN_STACK     NUM_ARGS
    MOV             R9,2
    MOV             R8,1
    LEA             RDX,strHello
    LEA             RCX,strFormat4
    SUB             RSP,32
    CALL            printf
    RESTORE_STACK   NUM_ARGS
    POP             RSP    
    
    ; ExitProcess with 1 arg

    NUM_ARGS        = 1
    PUSH            RSP
    PUSH            QWORD PTR [RSP]
    ALIGN_STACK     NUM_ARGS
    MOV             RCX,0
    SUB             RSP,32
    CALL            ExitProcess
    RESTORE_STACK   NUM_ARGS
    POP             RSP           

    RET
main endp

end
```

Built using these commands

```
@echo on

if not defined DevEnvDir (
  call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
)

ml64.exe hello.asm /link /subsystem:console /defaultlib:kernel32.lib /defaultlib:libcmt.lib
```

**NASM Example**

```
section .data
strFormat6 db "%s %d %d %d %d",13,10,0
strFormat5 db "%s %d %d %d",13,10,0  
strFormat4 db "%s %d %d",13,10,0       
strHello   db "Hello World",0

extern printf
extern ExitProcess

%macro ALIGN_STACK 1
    %if (%1 < 5) || ((%1 & 1) == 0)
        and spl, 0F0h
    %else
        or spl, 08h
    %endif
%endmacro

%macro RESTORE_STACK 1
    %if %1 < 5
        lea rsp, [rsp + 5*8]
    %elif (%1 & 1) == 0
        lea rsp, [rsp + (%1 + 1)*8]
    %else
        lea rsp, [rsp + %1*8]
    %endif
%endmacro

section .text

global main
main:

    ; printf with 6 args
    
    %define         NUM_ARGS 6 
    push            rsp
    push            qword [rsp]
    ALIGN_STACK     NUM_ARGS
    push            4
    push            3
    mov             r9,2
    mov             r8,1
    lea             rdx,strHello
    lea             rcx,strFormat6
    sub             rsp,32
    call            printf
    RESTORE_STACK   NUM_ARGS
    pop             rsp

    ; printf with 5 args
    
    %define         NUM_ARGS 5
    push            rsp
    push            qword [rsp]
    ALIGN_STACK     NUM_ARGS
    push            3
    mov             r9,2
    mov             r8,1
    lea             rdx,strHello
    lea             rcx,strFormat5
    sub             rsp,32
    call            printf
    RESTORE_STACK   NUM_ARGS
    pop             rsp    

    ; printf with 4 args
    
    %define         NUM_ARGS 4
    push            rsp
    push            qword [rsp]
    ALIGN_STACK     NUM_ARGS
    mov             r9,2
    mov             r8,1
    lea             rdx,strHello
    lea             rcx,strFormat4
    sub             rsp,32
    call            printf
    RESTORE_STACK   NUM_ARGS
    pop             rsp

    ; ExitProcess with 1 arg
    
    %define         NUM_ARGS 1
    push            rsp
    push            qword [rsp]
    ALIGN_STACK     NUM_ARGS
    mov             rcx,0
    sub             rsp,32
    call            ExitProcess
    RESTORE_STACK   NUM_ARGS
    pop             rsp          

    ret
```

Built using these commands

```
@echo on

if not defined DevEnvDir (
  call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
)

nasm -fwin64 -o hello.obj hello.asm
link hello.obj /LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO /subsystem:console /out:hello.exe kernel32.lib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib msvcrt.lib
```

The output is

```
Hello World 1 2 3 4
Hello World 1 2 3
Hello World 1 2
```

**Question**

The above technique is a "clever" trick to restore RSP because the RSP value is put on the stack **TWICE**. So, whatever the result of the alignment via `OR SPL, 08h` or `AND SPL, 0F0h`, RSP can be restored.

I'm curious about the pros and cons of using this technique.

**Pros**

- GoAsm inserts special coding before and after each API call to ensure that the stack is always properly aligned at the time of the call. This liberates the assembler programmer.
- Calls to APIs can be made anywhere in your code. They can be made from procedures called by other procedures without worrying about the stack pointer.
- `PUSH`'s and `POP`'s can be used in the usual way to save and restore registers, memory addresses and contents of memory without having to worry that this puts the stack out of alignment.

**Cons**

- The overhead for aligning the stack at the time of each API call is an additional 9 bytes per API, which seems a small price to pay for the advantages gained.

Comment: All this senseless here and not need in windows. This is pure cons without any pros. Alignment of rsp is known at function entry point. This is `16*n+8`. We not need align stack before every api call. We need do this only once, in function prolog. Never need `and` or `or` for `rsp`. Not need `push` before api call, but `mov [rsp+20h],*` for 5th param, `mov [rsp+28h],*` for 6th and so on.

Comment: Is this where you got that clunky asm you posted as an answer on [How to calculate the position that the parameters should be pushed to when we use Windows x64 memory management by x64 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77106219) ?  Yuck.  Does Go's custom calling convention not maintain 16-byte stack alignment or something?  Other stuff I've seen from Go code-gen has shown a similar lack of care about efficiency, like passing all args on the stack (until very recently) instead of using good calling conventions that already exist on the platforms they target like x86-64.

Comment: Why would you be writing asm by hand if performance doesn't matter?  It's not just code-size, it also runs extra uops around each call, and puts a reload of the stack point as part of the dependency chain for RSP which will slow down out-of-order exec.  Not a big deal around "heavy" calls like system calls, but keeping track of RSP alignment wrt. a 16-byte boundary is not a problem in most code either.  As RbMn says, there's near zero advantage if you're following the standard Windows x64 calling convention for the caller so you already know RSP % 16 == 8 on function entry.

Comment: You untagged [windows], but didn't add a mention that this is the Windows x64 calling convention (with shadow space which is what makes `push` for args extra inconvenient.)

Comment: Also note that any change to RSP need to be marked with stack-unwind metadata ([as Raymond Chen points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77103422/how-to-calculate-the-position-that-the-parameters-should-be-pushed-to-when-we-us/77106219#comment135927722_77104257)), which is why it's normal for Windows functions to not modify RSP except in their prologue.  I suspect this hack of saving RSP twice is impossible to annotate for stack-unwind because the `OR` or `AND` modify RSP by an unknown amount.

Comment: AFAIK you can only do that if you've told stack-unwinding that RBP is a frame pointer, in which case this clunky way of restoring RSP isn't necessary.